# Generate a random password using urandom in bash script

Tags: bash, random, passwords

I'm trying to make a 3-digit random password in linux, but with below condition:

- Using urandom
- at least one uppercase
- at least one lowercase
- at least one numeric

Comment: this could be starting point `perl -le 'print map{(a..z,A..Z,0..9)[rand 62]} 0..2'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I was going to sugggest `pwgen -n -c 3` (why reinvent the wheel) as it uses `/dev/urandom` (per `strace`) but apparently you can't force it to include a lowercase letter, only numerals and capitals.

Comment: `printf $'%s%s%s\n' $({ printf '%s\n' {A..Z} | shuf | head -n 1 ; printf '%s\n' {a..z} | shuf | head -n 1; printf '%s\n' {0..9} | shuf | head -n1; } | shuf )` random order for digit, upper and lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over a list of randomly ordered regex `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`, and pass the regex to `tr`:

```sh
for regex in $(sort -R <(printf "a-z\nA-Z\n0-9")); do
    head -c 100 /dev/urandom | tr -dc $regex | head -c 1
done
```

Sample outputs: `Z7a`, `Kp4`, `0jN`, `9bE`, `1cA`

Comment: This code doesn't always output 3 characters.  When I ran it 100,000 times in a loop it output 2 characters 1880 times and 1 character once.  The problem is that there is a small probability that  a string of 100 characters will not contain one of the types of character that is required.  This is particularly true for digits, because there are only 10 of them out of 256 possible characters.  (Almost all of the two-character outputs were missing a digit.)